# how to embed SWF into FLA in Flash CS5?

Tags: flash

I have a problem including a SWF into FLA using Flash CS5. I am new to Flash and actionscript. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 1):

When you import a swf, you get a framebyframe animation in your timeline, which can be useful sometimes but I bet that's not what you want.

You have to go Actionscript, [guide](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html) from Adobe

Not being rude, just a recommendation:  
You should read a book or a lot of tutorials first to understand the basics and start asking questions from there.

AS2 might be easier to learn if you haven't been programming that much but I recommend learning AS3. Good luck!